# How to create a dataframe with column names containing 2d array and regular column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have trained Simple Linear Regression algorithm.
I supplied new data in it as 2d array and got an output.

Now I want create a dataframe with 2 columns: `NewData`, and `Prediction`

```
new_data = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]) # 2d array

# predicting
y_pred = regressor.predict(new_data)

#create dataframe containing new_data and predicted data
df = pd.DataFrame( new_data, y_pred, columns = ['NewData'])
df
```

How can I create a column name for `y_pred` in my dataframe?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

tried:

```
new_data = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
y_pred = regressor.predict(new_data)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y_pred': y_pred, 'new_data': new_data})
df
```

Error:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: You could simply do `df =df.reset_index()` and rename the column, but there is probably a way to do it when creating the dataframe itself. I'd have to have a quick look at the documentation.

Comment: use a dictionary instead `pd.DataFrame({'y_pred' : y_pred, 'new_data' : new_data})`

Comment: @Datanovice that's generally how I create all my DataFrames if not reading thm in, which is why I'm unfamiliar with all of the other arguments with `pd.DataFrame`. It seems like a dict is almost always the best approach.

Comment: @DavidErickson the dataframe constructor is very useful esp when working with json, xml, or numpy arrays that you have flattened

Comment: Thank you , tried using dictionary gives me an error: Data must be 1-dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy solution is to flatten your `new_data` array and then pass it in a dictionary to create your new dataframe:

```
new_data = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
y_pred = regressor.predict(new_data)

df = pd.DataFrame({'y_pred': y_pred, 'new_data': new_data.flatten()})
```